# Ensure data consistency when same stored procedure is called by windows service in interval of few seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure which returns the list of the pending items which need to be processed. Now there is a window service which calls a stored procedure in intervals of 20 seconds to get the pending items for further processing.

There is a column `QueryTimestamp` in the `Pending` table. For the pending items the `QueryTimestamp` column is null. Once selected by the a stored procedure, the column `QueryTimestamp` is updated with current date time.

The body is as followed. No explicit transaction has been used. SQL Server default isolation level is applicable.

```
DECLARE @workerPending TABLE
    (
        RowNum INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        [PendingId] BIGINT,
        [CreatedDate] DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO @workerPending ([PendingId], [CreatedDate])
     SELECT 
         [p].[PendingId] AS [PendingId],
         [p].CreatedDate
     FROM   
         [pending] [p] 
     WHERE          
         [p].QueryTimestamp IS NULL 
     ORDER BY
         [p].[PendingId]

--Update pending table with current date time
UPDATE Pnd  
SET QueryTimestamp = GETDATE()
FROM [Pending] Pnd
INNER JOIN @workerPending [wp] ON [wp].[PendingId] = Pnd.[PendingId]
```

If the stored procedure is not able to process the first request in 20 seconds due to huge data, windows service sends another call to the stored procedure, and it starts processing both the requests.

Concern is: does this causes both the requests have some duplicate pending records?

Do we need to implement LOCK in the pending table ?

Please suggest how we can ensure data consistency? SO that if another request comes to the stored procedure while the previous request is still in progress, no duplicate record should be returned.

EDIT : Other windows service is there which calls another SP which inserts records into the Pending table and mark "QueryTimestamp" with null.

Comment: You don't need that `INSERT` clause, or the `ORDER` on it. You could have included that query as a subquery in the `UPDATE`. Or create a self-join. THe `HERE 
    Pnd.[PendingId] = [wp].[PendingId]` clause is redundant since that's the JOIN condition too. You should probably rethink the way this stored procedure is written

Comment: In fact, that's equivalent to just `UPDATE Pnd  
SET QueryTimestamp = GETDATE()
FROM [Pending] Pnd where QueryTimestamp IS NULL`. If you want to store the modified rows for later, you can use the `OUTPUT` clause

Comment: I have updated the query but my concern is does that ensure  that no duplicate data will be returned while the first request is not served and the second request arrives ?

Comment: If you use SQL Server Agent or another task scheduler to run the job, there won't be any second request as long as the first is still running. Isolation is ensured by *transactions*. UPDATE is atomic, which means it will run in a single transaction. During that transaction, assuming the default isolation level is at `READ COMMITTED`, other transactions won't be able to access any affected rows.

Answer (score 0):

Simple but effective solution is when the service wants to call the SP do this :

```
Read in table Settings a value that tells you if the thread is already running
If not already running then
begin
     Write to table Settings that the thread has started
     Commit this update
     Call your SP
     Write to table Settings that the thread has finished
     Commit this update
end
```

Comment: I am not very much clear about what you mentioned. I am not entitled to make any changes in the table structure.

Comment: some changes cannot be made without changing a table structure. If you  are not allowed to do that, than you are not allowed to fix the problem. This is stupid by whoever gave you this assigment. In this case you dont need to change the table structure, you can create a new table just to hold a flag that you can use to know your SP is already running.

Comment: In my answer there is not any code. There is just a description about how your service should work. It tells you the logic that your service should use when calling the SP so it will never call the SP while a prior call is not finished yet

Answer (score -1):

You can do the UPDATE and SELECT in a single step with an [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.  EG

```
UPDATE pending  
SET QueryTimestamp = GETDATE()
output inserted.PendingId, inserted.CreatedDate
into @workerPending(PendingId,CreatedDate)
WHERE QueryTimestamp IS NULL
```

Or a more robust pattern that allows you to limit and order the results and concurrently retrieve them is to use a transaction and lock hints on the SELECT, eg:

```
    begin transaction 

         INSERT INTO @workerPending ([PendingId], [CreatedDate])
         SELECT top 100
             [p].[PendingId] AS [PendingId],
             [p].CreatedDate
         FROM   
             [pending] [p] with (updlock, rowlock, readpast)
         WHERE          
             [p].QueryTimestamp IS NULL 
         ORDER BY
             [p].[PendingId];

        UPDATE pending 
        SET QueryTimestamp = GETDATE()
        where PendingIdin (select PendingId from @workerPending )

    commit transaction
```

See [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

Comment: That's *not* what the link shows. You aren't treating the table as a queue here. In fact, you *can't* use a table as a queue with an `UPDATE` statement. There's a reason all `table-as-queue` article use destructive reads, ie `DELETE` with and OUTPUT clause to pop entries. Instead of being more robust, this transaction will lead to deadlocks. You can imagine how I know ...

Comment: You can make this a single UPDATE … OUTPUT query if you like with a CTE, but it doesn't materially change the locking behavior.

Comment: Will it guarantee data consistency if two threads comes in same time and no duplicate record is received by the caller ? I am talking about more than 700 records.

Comment: Yes.  It's guaranteed with both that new two sessions will get the same rows.  However it is important to keep the table structures simple and test that you don't get deadlocks.